# Location for app-wide utils file in a Django project

Tags: python, django, relative-import

Given the [nightmare of relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time), where should I put a simple `utils.py` file in a Django project that has multiple apps (accessible within the `models.py`, `admin.py`, `views.py` all files of all app directories)?

It seems like there still isn't a good answer for this in 2019, even though Django is by far the most popular framework of the language.

Considering Python 2 will be sunset in January of 2020, please also provide an answer for Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295268/where-should-utility-functions-live-in-django) addresses this.

Reading this, it was unclear to me as I wasn't sure it was possible for Django to import from a directory or get another nested file to do so, but it appears if you create a `common/utils.py` file in the root directory (same directory as `manage.py`), any file within the apps will be able to resolve that import at `manage.py`'s runtime.

You would simply `import common.utils` and `utils.foo()` within an app-directories file.

I still don't know how Django makes this happen.